# Adobe Omniture DPS Track Custom Event

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I was just wondering, where in Omniture will the custom events appear? I have the following code:

```
var scope = this;

scope.customAnalyicsTracker('customEvent1','Subscribe_Clicked');

customAnalyicsTracker: function(realName,variable){
    adobeDPS.analyticsService.trackCustomEvent(realName,variable);
}
```

The code above doesn't error out but I dont see it in Site Catalyst. I'm looking under Custom HTML > Custom Events > Custom Events 1 and I don't see it.

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong in the above code or if I'm looking in the wrong spot in Site Catalyst.

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using the Adobe Analytics (SiteCatalyst) enterprise option to do your DPS analytics you can use the following custom events (varies a bit on SDK version I believe but enumerable from AnalyticsService.ALLOWED_EVENTS).
    "customEvent1",
    "customEvent2",
    "customEvent3",
    "customEvent4",
    "customEvent5",
    "customEvent6",
    "customEvent7",
    "customEvent8",
    "customEvent9",
    "customEvent10"

And they are pre-wired to these internal Sitecatalyst events.
events 46-50 and 96-100.

More details here: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/dps/analytics-report/dps-analytics-report-guide.pdf page 61.

Also, an event is a Metric, so this is some sort of number. So the second parameter(variables    String  Other variables to be assigned to the event) likely needs to follow the SiteCatalyst event constraints. They are of type "Counter" so you can either increment them by 1(no value) or an integer number. I have not tired this, but that is what I assume.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! The link was very helpful.